# sklearn confusion_matrix: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 1)

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am getting this error while running the eval report. I trained my model with bert-base-german-cased for my custom dataset.

The code is as follows:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

...
tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(labels, preds).ravel()
```

and the error is

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-0d7757abd7dd> in <module>
     10         model = model_class.from_pretrained(checkpoint)
     11         model.to(device)
---> 12         result, wrong_preds = evaluate(model, tokenizer, prefix=global_step)
     13         result = dict((k + '_{}'.format(global_step), v) for k, v in result.items())
     14         results.update(result)

<ipython-input-30-c0946f859f89> in evaluate(model, tokenizer, prefix)
     76     elif args['output_mode'] == "regression":
     77         preds = np.squeeze(preds)
---> 78     result, wrong = compute_metrics(EVAL_TASK, preds, out_label_ids)
     79     results.update(result)
     80 

<ipython-input-30-c0946f859f89> in compute_metrics(task_name, preds, labels)
     25 def compute_metrics(task_name, preds, labels):
     26     assert len(preds) == len(labels)
---> 27     return get_eval_report(labels, preds)
     28 
     29 def evaluate(model, tokenizer, prefix=""):

<ipython-input-30-c0946f859f89> in get_eval_report(labels, preds)
     14 def get_eval_report(labels, preds):
     15     mcc = matthews_corrcoef(labels, preds)
---> 16     tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(labels, preds).ravel()
     17     return {
     18         "mcc": mcc,
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Can you share the full traceback so we can see which line causes that error more clearly?

Comment: @MustafaAydın i have pasted the traceback at the end.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

sklearn's confusion matrix returns a 1-element 1D array when all the predictions and ground truth match. For example:

```py
>>> confusion_matrix([1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]).ravel()
array([4], dtype=int64)
```

So even though we might have been dealing with binary classification here, i.e., 0 and 1, `confusion_matrix` naturally has no idea. But there is a way to tell this and it is the `labels` parameter:

```py
>>> confusion_matrix([1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], labels=[0, 1]).ravel()
array([0, 0, 0, 4], dtype=int64)
```

Now it is okay: we have 4 TPs and no sample for other 3 fields.

So you should give `labels` argument with your possible 2 classification values, e.g., [0, 1].